# How set style from an option in wordpress (settings API)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress theme with an admin panel where the user can change the color of the paragraphs, the body background, and more style options. I'm saving this options using the Settings API, so I have the colors in the database and with get_option() function I get all the options.

My problem is that I don't know how can I to add this style. I show on internet  that you can do something like this:

```
function my_custom_theme_style(){

    $bodyColor = get_option('boon_body_color');
    $paragraphColor = get_option('boon_paragraph_color');

    return 'body{
    color: ' . $bodyColor . ' !important;
    }
    p{
    color: ' . $paragraphColor . ' !important;
    }';
}

function add_custom_style(){
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo my_custom_theme_style();
    echo '</style>';
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_style');
```

But the problem is that all the scripts are enqueuing on the body instead the head

Thanks a million!

Comment: Try `wp_head` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`.
`add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_style');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right action hook: `wp_head` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_style');
```

---

**But maybe there is a better way:**

Have a look: [wp_add_inline_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) (show the example in there)

Comment: The second way is fine for me. Thank you!!